# Angular2 dynamic component in run time + packing whole app

Tags: angular, dynamic, components, angular-cli

I'm trying to find a way to dynamically inject components into main/module angular2 app. I have set up and API  to send a list of components to inject (for example BookingInComponent), but I don't want this to exist on the app before certain action.

I've managed to do this in AngularJS(1) by attaching each controller to template via , injecting it in routes in mainApp.js, so they were loading with them.

I can't find a way to do this in Angular2, as everything has to be pre-defined in main.ts~, and even if its lazy loaded later on - there seems to be no easy way to 'pack' it with AngularCLI.

**Just to clarify -> I am not looking for anything that will hide my routes with 
[hidden]="!notLoggedIn()" or protect my routes when user is not logged in -> I'm looking for a way to NOT HAVE THE COMPONENTS if an user should not have it at all (=**

Comment: I am doing something similar in one project and I generate different bundles or apps. I have one plain Auth app, and five other apps. The code base is all shared, except the AppModule - I have five AppModules. I am planning to create a simple cli project to handle this better for my purpose

Comment: Seems like it's gonna compicate a lot - I imagine it's different bundle for each user type then. Could be a real problem when handling like 20 different user types = 20 different app bundles O_O

Comment: Not at all, with lazyLoaded routes, it is a matter of enabling the routes or features needed for a particular App, essentially great UX is my goal with one codebase. By all means good luck with your research!

Comment: But with lazy loaded modules it's not possible to minify and pack the whole app..It's not about enabling/disabling routes -> I don't want the whole components in the app if they are not required :)

Comment: @Shivan did you ever get this figured out? I'm a novice with Angular and have similar needs for the application.